# Correct tense of verb in passive voice sentence

Tags: tenses, passive-voice

I have written the sentence

> One difficulty when performing a numerical integral arises when one does not know the exact function being used (for example, in signal processing), but **is** instead cumulatively calculating data points that are then fed into an integral function.

"Is" sounds incorrect here; what should the verb be? I tried "are", but that doesn't sound right either. Would it be better to split up the sentence?

In short, how can I formulate this so that it is grammatically correct?

Comment: @PeterShor, yup, I mistyped, it should be "function"

Comment: "one does not know", "one is" (i.e., one is the subject of is, it seems to me

Comment: @Xanne it does sound a little over-done, but that works. It certainly sounds better than before. Thanks =)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it needed to be changed; I was just explaining how I'd parse it.  I thought you were quoting something.

Comment: @Xanne nope, writing something. Edited to clarify.

Comment: "when one does not know… but instead cumulatively calculates…"

Comment: @Kevin, this option sounds really good, thank you. Could you write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither *is* nor *are* will make this sound right; the correct approach is to make the verb tenses in the phrases match:

> when one does not know… but instead cumulatively calculates…